# Is there a way to query from an Oracle SQL database directly using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

Is there a way to query from an Oracle SQL database directly using VBA without utilizing a power query connection. We currently do this with a oracle to excel setup and every pc has to have the setup done but its becoming a real hassle setting that up on every pc in our workplace and are trying to find a better solution for our excel reports that need to query the oracle database. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose you could consider using `=WEBSERVICE(url)` formula. then the setup will only be used once; and you don't even need vba (xlsm).

Comment: is the oracle client installed on each machine?

Comment: We currently have our IT department setup the oracle to excel connection setup on each pc which i believe has the client in it. We have other tools that use microsoft sql that do not require any setups to be done and we do that through vba. I was just seeing if that can be done for Oracle SQL as well. The setups are quite a burden on our IT department given the size of our business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though you are trying to skip the fairly onerous process of installing the Oracle client on each machine.  For a machine to talk directly to an Oracle server, it must have the Oracle client installed.  Once that is installed, you can query it directly from VBA.

Another approach would be to set up a machine that is configured to access Oracle that is running a web server.  That machine could take requests from the local network specifying the connection credentials and then relay those requests to the oracle server.  That way, your individual machines do not need to be configured to hit Oracle directly.  This is how we do it where I work.

The reason that your tools that use SQL Server don't need any direct configuration is because the SQL Server client comes pre-installed on Windows.

Here's how we make the request from VBA to the server that actually makes the query to the oracle database

```
Sub remote_data_query()

    Const query = "select * from redcat.customer"
    Dim formdata As String
    
    formdata = "sql=" & URLEncode("select * from redcat.customer")
    formdata = formdata & "&cs=Oracle"
    formdata = formdata & "&un=redcat_user"
    formdata = formdata & "&pw=" & URLEncode("Pa55w0rd")
    formdata = formdata & "&m=2"
    formdata = formdata & "&style=ascii2"
    
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim myurl As String
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    myurl = "https://dbrelayserver.websql.org/sql.aspx"
    xmlhttp.Open "POST", myurl, False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xmlhttp.Send formdata
    
    Debug.Print xmlhttp.responseText

End Sub
```

The response comes back as a formatted string which we parse and write into a worksheet.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses, i will ask around and see about setting up the recommendation you suggested using the one pc that would be a lot better than doing it for each pc. If we did have the client on each pc how would i go about running a query in VBA on it? we currently setup a data connection for it.

Comment: I'll address this question with a separate answer

Comment: thank you im new to this website today so im probably not doing this correctly.

Comment: I updated my prior answer rather than making a new one.  If this is helpful, please mark it as the selected answer